# What is typical depth in binary decision tree in practice

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying out optimized implementation of binary decision tree.
I want to know that what is the typical depth of binary decision tree in practice.
E.g. consider implementation in https://github.com/pdollar/toolbox/blob/master/detector/private/acfDetect1.cpp

Is depth in boosted trees would be smaller than non-boosted trees?

Comment: This question may be suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) because it is more a stats practice question than a language-specific programming question.... if you are asking a matlab question use the matlab tag.

Comment: Why not find this using cross-validation on your particular dataset? Alternatively, use other criteria that will influence the height, e.g., min samples for split (of course, those will require cross-validation as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a typical depth. It solely depends on the data/problem considered. You might expect boosted trees to use shallow trees, as boosting is supposed to fit your training data better, and so is using deeper trees - consequently there is rather no point in using both methods in the same time.

Comment: Thanks @lejlot for your answer. So what would be maximum shallow tree depth? Do people use more than depth 2 decision tress with boosting? I searched through research papers. But could not exactly find the answer. (I am little new to the field)

Comment: There is no answer to such questions - again. There are **relative** answers - that you will use deeper trees without boosting, but no answer of type "at most X!". I would say that people even use depth 1 (called decision stub) which is a default in scikit-learn adaboost for example. But there is no actual maximum. Everything depends on the problem